# Ctrl+'Click' in Excel (and then offset the cells selected)

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with writing a code in macro that will select multiple cells given those I've selected with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ `Click`.

What I mean by this is, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ `Click` to select multiple cells, I want a macro to then select those cells plus the 5 cells to the right. However, I'm unsure what the code would be for Excel to know what cells I've selected from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ `Click`.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The cells you have selected by any means (including Ctrl-click) prior to running the macro will be found in `ActiveSheet.Selection`. Are you saying you want the macro to add to the current selection the cell to the right of each cell already in the selection?

Comment: I mean "..the five cells to the right of each cell already in the selection".

Comment: I think you can look into `Offset`. You need to show what you've done so far

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for the quick replies. I think I had a mental blank and forgot I could totally just use Selection.Offset().Range().Select. I was just having issues with trying to run code when I have 'multiple selected/active' cells.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to loop through the areas of the current selection to resize the selection if you selected multiple not continuous cells:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectPlusFiveColumns()
    Dim FinalRange As Range

    Dim Area As Range
    For Each Area In Selection.Areas 'loop through areas
        If FinalRange Is Nothing Then
            Set FinalRange = Area.Resize(ColumnSize:=6)
        Else
            Set FinalRange = Union(FinalRange, Area.Resize(ColumnSize:=6)) 'resize each area and collect all areas in FinalRange
        End If
    Next Area

    FinalRange.Select 'select all resized areas
End Sub
```

Note: Selection of overlapping areas will be combined to one area.